# Jboss default deployer war size is more than the same export using eclipse .why?

Tags: jboss

I have created the workspace in eclipse. I set up a Jboss server for the code deployment. On staring on the Jboss server the new ear is created in the deploy directory of Jboss.Then I have export EAR using export as EAR option available in Eclipse.I found that the Jboss created EAR size is more than eclipse created EAR size. Anyone came across same scenario.? 
Note :My ear file not contain any jsp files and its having xsl files.Its a webservice application.

Answer (score 2):

Un zip the ear from eclipse  in some local hard drives and check the file size. The same ear from jboss also un zip and chek the file size.you will find both file size is same.If you check the Jboss ear's compression raio you will find it is zero but for the eclipse compression ratio is 100.Its problem of compression mechanisam used ( creating ear file in jboss and eclipse)